# How do I use the root Uri of the SD card to find a file inside a folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I need to rename files that are in subfolders in the SD card so I got the root Uri of the Sd card with the permission `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_Document_TREE`. Whenever I use `documentFile.findFile()` it only finds files that are in the root path(files that are not in subfolders).How do I find other files that are not in the root path.

Comment: You should list the contents of the folder. You will then get files and subdirectories. Then you can do the same with the subdirectories. Like you were used to do with classic file paths.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but listing the files was not necessary,all I needed to do was to split the absolute path with this regex "/" then call documentFile.findFile() for each of the split paths till I reached the folder containing the desired file.

Comment: do not be vexed we are all here to learn from others

Answer (score 0):

```
String exampleAbsolutePath="/storage/sdCardName/Folder1/Folder2/myFile.mp4"; 
String []splitPathArray=exampleAbsolutePath.split("/");
DocumentFile documentFile= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(myContext,sdCardRootUri);//sdCardRootUri is the **Root** Uri got from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_Document_TREE

for(int pos=3;pos<splitPath.length;++pos){//pos starts from 3 because the sdCardRootUri is pointing to the sdCardName and we need to start searching from Folder1
 documentFile=documentFile.findFile(splitPath[pos]);}//findFile() can take both files and folders,it takes the file or folder display name(i.e the name of the file(with the extension e.g file.mp4,photo.png in the **exampleAbsolutePath** the file name is myFile.mp4) or the folderName e.g Music Folder,Photo Album,Videos,Documents in the **exampleAbsolutPath** the folder display names we iterate through are Folder1 and Folder2) 
                                      
if(documentFile!=null){
  documentFile.renameTo(newDisplayName);}//rename old file display Name to the new file dispaly name
```

You might want to do this file rename in a Thread as it can be a little bit slow.